# Symfony3 Doctrine2 Column cannot be null

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine

**[PROBLEM SOLVED]**

Hey folks I need your help on a symfony project.

I have two entities, "article" and "image", article can have several images so I made a relationship OneToMany on the article side and ManyToOne on the image side. Doctrine generates for me an "article_id" column on the image table. 
I made a form to create an article with one or more images... however when I execute it I have an error that is thrown :

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO image (url, alt, article_id) VALUES (?,?,?) 'with params ["jpeg", "untitled.jpg", null]: SQLSTATE [23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column' article_id 'can not be null.

When I look to the profiler logs debug, I can see that I have an "INSERT INTO article[...]" (so the article is created with an ID ?) and just after this I have the famous "INSERT INTO image[...]" where the error occurs.

Thank you for your help.

**EDIT In bold you will find the lines I added to solve this problem.**

I added into the ArticleType form, in the images collection options this :

**'by_reference' => false**

And I added to the addImage method into the Article entity this :

**$image->setArticle($this);**

**$this->images->add($image);**

Comment: Ah yes.  The shotgun approach.  You go from no code to posting everything.  And yet the solution I posted yesterday is not shown.  Very sad.  Here is a thought.  Make yourself two new entities with just the relation that article/image has.  Get rid of the rest of the nonsense which is just causing confusion.  Get the two new entities to post properly and voila you may understand what is happening.

Comment: Better yet, follow the example in the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: Thank you @Cerad. The documentation lead me to solve the issue. I added the line that you told me in your first answer : $image->setArticle($this) and I added also in the same method $this->images->add($image). I also added to my form images collection options 'by_reference' => false. Lesson learn ! RTFM !

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question but surprisingly difficult to search for.  In fact the first ten or so search results had incorrect answers.

In any event, you need to make sure that image is linked to the article.

```
class Article
    public function addImage($image) {
        $this->images[] = $image;
        $image->setArticle($this); // ADD THIS
```

Comment: Thank you Cerad.

However I did add the line $image->setArticle($this) but I got the exact same error...

Comment: Do I have to do the same thing in the Image entity ?

Comment: Think about what would happen if you did add the line or try it.  Do make sure you emptied out your database since your existing images are now invalid.  Verify that Article::addImage is being called.  You did not include any details about your entities or form so I am relying primarily on my psychic powers to debug this.

Comment: So far you've done pretty good with these powers ah ah. How can I check if Article::addImage is being called ? Another person told me that it was better to do $image->setArticle($article) in my controller... If you want I'll paste my code. Thanks again.

Comment: A simple die statement will do the trick.  Try to avoid adding code to the controller because then you will need to run the code every time an image is added.  Which would be a pain.  On the other hand, you could add it as a debugging tool just to verify the cross linking is the problem.  Then remove it once you have things working.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Cerad's answer is very wrong, although I can't blame him because OP hasn't posted enough code, don't be shy with it, we're here to help. It also helps to briefly mention if you're just starting out (as I suspect you are) as it will help us gauge whether its a novice problem or something deeper.

Since I'm assuming it's a novice problem here is the novice solution.

With they way you've mapped (which I believe is correct) you are basically telling Doctrine to Tell your RDBMS (MySql/MariaDB/PostgreSQL) that an article CAN have many images, but an image MUST belong to an article.

This means that if you attempt to save an image without specifying the owning article, it will throw an error.

This is what I think you are doing evident in the line

> (url, alt, article_id) VALUES (?,?,?) 'with params ["jpeg", "untitled.jpg", null]

the value "null" is where the issue is coming about because you are not specifying the owning article.

You have 2 options

1.) When saving image, if you have the article object at hand just do

```
$image->setArticle($article);
```

2.) When saving the image, if you have the article_id at hand just do

```
$image->setArticle($em->getReference('AppBundle\Entity\Articles', $article_id));
```

You must follow one of the above when saving an image directly.

My general experience has been that Doctrine does a really good job of generating entities from command line that you really don't need to change much unless adding some advanced functionality like second_level_cache or MySQL point type.

Cheers.

Comment: While you are correct in that the basic problem is that the image has not been linked to the article, I suspect that once you have used the Doctrine 2 ORM for a bit you will understand that your proposed workarounds are not really all that convenient and are unnecessary.  Especially when using the Symfony form collection component.

Comment: I think we'll let the OP decide when he gets back to us. When I say your answer is wrong, I mean in the context of the question, which I admit is not your fault if my assumptions are right. If they're not, I'm happy to admit it and not defend it. It's wrong to ask the OP to edit the entities if the problem is (assumably) how he persists records to DB. Its worse when you add die to the mix.

Comment: Just to add so that you don't think I was being unfair, I also thought telling OP to empty DB was a terrible idea because, correct me if I'm wrong, "exception occurred while executing" means that nothing was saved into DB unless OP was saving in multiple flushes, so why clear out DB?

Comment: Hey ! Thanks Don. Well you're right, I'm a novice... So where exactly do I have to put one of the two solutions ? Because I tried to add $image->setArticle($article) in the controller (I also add $image = new Image()) just before the persist but I got the same error...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you submit your form, the first image is attached to the article but the others are not, so you get an SQL error.
You have to do a "foreach loop" for every image and attched the article to each one. 
Look here at the addAction function
https://github.com/ismail1432/TheGoodLoc/blob/master/Symfony/src/VTC/AnnonceBundle/Controller/AdvertController.php

Comment: The form collection will call addImage for each new image.  The poster verified this yesterday.  Absolutely no need for any extra loops.